.ZPL Dynamically Show / Hide Data
I have a Label where 1 Field of data needs to Show/ hide based on the value from another parameter . is it possible to do this within Zebra Designer ? I can see a Box Scripts but not sure of the Correct format / language and there are limited .zpl videos out in the wild

